# MbTest(MounteBank) vs WireMock vs Mock-server vs anyother for encrypted payload

Tags: encryption, stub, wiremock, mockserver, mountebank

we need to decide a mock-server for our applications. We have an ask in which the applications sends encrypted payload in request and response . that encryption is using rsa so the encrypted string changes for same payload so it is not possible to know by inspecting the encrypted string which request it is. and we should be able to inspect the payload and send the appropriate response. Have looked into the above three mockservers, I know mock-server has class callback mechanism through which i could decrypt the request and send but mock-server itself doesnt look that appealing. Anyone has any idea how can we mock encrypted request. ?